# How to make downloads available to approved download requests?

Tags: users, files

The idea here is any registered user can attach a file to a certain node. However, users have to request for download access from the node author to be able to get the file.

I've searched for file access related modules and so far, they are all role-based. My need is per-author && per-requestor && per-node based.

Is there an existing module for this? Or is there another way to achieve this by linking certain modules together? Connect the dots?